# can i create assetbundle without editor by Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

use `UnityEditor.dll`, how to create assetbundle?

when using `UnityEditor.dll` to `Execute BuildPipeline.CreateAssetbundle()` to create like that in Unity3d editor, it will not work.

does it must be run in Unity Editor?

Answer (score 2):

Since creating AssetBundles is only for Pro versions of Unity3D, you cannot use the DLL outside the editor.

If you are looking to create some automated tool to export the bundle, you can also use Unity with in batch mode and without graphics. Check out the [Command Line Arguments](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) available.